# how I append array in array as last element with key In PHP i need below output..?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, arraylist

How could I append array in an array as last element with an key in PHP?
I need the below output.

My current code is :

```
 $qr=mysql_query("SELECT * from category") or die(mysql_error());




$rows = array();

   while($r= mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)) 
   {
      $qr2=mysql_query("SELECT subcatname from subcategory where catname='".$r['catname']."'") or die(mysql_error());
      $rows2 = array();


        $rows['response'][] = $r;
      while($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr2)) 
      {



          $rows2[]=$r2;
      // $rows['subcatname'] = $r2;

      }
            $rows['response'][]= $rows2;

   }

      echo  (json_encode($rows));
```

I get an output like this..

```
{"response":[{"id":"1","catname":"Fruits & Vegetables","cattagline":"Potato, Tomato, Apples","catimg":"qwrefrweafwsfg"},[{"subcatname":"FRUITS"},{"subcatname":"VEGETABLES"},{"subcatname":"FROZEN"}],{"id":"4","catname":"Dairy","cattagline":"dsgfasgtersa","catimg":"sfsdafgasg"},[{"subcatname":"Milk & CURD"}]]}
```

I need the subcatname to insert with catname,cattagline,..
like below:

```
{"response":[{"id":"1","catname":"Fruits & Vegetables","cattagline":"Potato, Tomato, Apples","catimg":"qwrefrweafwsfg","subcatname":{"0":"Fruits","1":"VEGETABLES"}},{"id":"4","catname":"Dairy","cattagline":"dsgfasgtersa","catimg":"sfsdafgasg","subcatname":{"0":"Milk & CURD"}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try array_ push.
This is a link for [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)